# PDF of joint multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand what this means:

$\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}}|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}, A) 
= 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{t}}|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}, A)  d\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}} d\boldsymbol{\mathrm{t}}$
which appears in section 2, on page 3 of this paper:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/trueskilltm-a-bayesian-skill-rating-system/

I take it from the text that $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}}$, $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{t}}$ are vectors of normally distributed random variables thusly (for a game involving two teams of two):

$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}} = \left[ \begin{array}{c} S_1 \\ S_2 \\ S_3 \\ S_4 \end{array} \right]$
$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}} = \left[ \begin{array}{c} P_1 \\ P_2 \\ P_3 \\ P_4 \end{array} \right]$
$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{t}} = \left[ \begin{array}{c} T_1 \\ T_2 \end{array} \right]$

And further that these vectors contain random variables that follow Normal distributions and are tightly inter-related as follows:

$S_i \sim \mathcal{N}(s_i | \mu^2, \sigma^2) 
\implies 
\mathcal{P}(s_i) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(s_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$
$\begin{align*}
P_i \sim \mathcal{N}(p_i|s_i,\beta^2) 
&\implies 
\mathcal{P}(p_i) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\beta^2}} e^{-\frac{(p_i-s_i)^2}{2\beta^2}}\\
&\implies 
\mathcal{P}(p_i) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma^2+\beta^2)}} e^{-\frac{(p_i-\mu)^2}{2 (\sigma^2 +\beta^2)}}
\end{align*}$
$\begin{align*}
T_j = \sum_{i=1}^{n_j} \omega_{ij} P_{ij}
&\implies
T_j \sim \mathcal{N}(t_j|\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}\omega_{ij}\mu_{ij}, \sum_{i=1}^{n_j}\omega_{ij}^2(\sigma_{ij}^2+\beta^2))\\
&\implies 
\mathcal{P}(t_i) = 
\frac
{1}
{\sqrt{2\pi\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}\omega_{ij}^2(\sigma_{ij}^2+\beta^2)}}
 e^{-\frac{(t_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}\omega_{ij}\mu_{ij})^2}{2 \sum_{i=1}^{n_j}\omega_{ij}^2(\sigma_{ij}^2+\beta^2)}}
\end{align*}$

that the matrix $A$ is simply some assignment of the players (so $S$ and $P$) to teams (so $T$) and $r$ remains a mystery for now in this context.

Taking things one step at a time and having read up at length on various sources about multivariate distributions and on joint distributions, and having looked for material on joint multivariate distributions I find myself stuck interpreting this:

$\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{t}}|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}, A)$

which is clearly a joint multivariate distribution. What I'm struggling to understand is what that looks like. Set aside $r$ and $A$ for now and consider just the joint multivariate distribution $\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{t}})$, is that a vector of probabilities, a matrix of probabilities, a scalar function of those three vectors or what? And what does it look like in the exemplar form, for the aforementioned game between 2 teams of 2 players.

It is an understanding of the nomenclature and what it means that I am struggling with I admit as none of the literature I've at hand or found on-line which deals wonderfully with multivariate distributions and well with joint distributions, has provided me with a concrete example of a joint multivariate distribution.

Of course, there is a chance I am misinterpreting things thus far too. But the paper is strong on assumed understanding of the nomenclature and I am using what I think are fairly normal interpretations thus far. Just a tad stumped on what this: $\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{t}})$ looks like and is in the exemplar form rather than the abstract form.

In any case to make sense of the integrals I would love to understand the integrand first though I don't rightly understand what the \cdots between the two integrals means and I wonder if the implication is that one integrates with respect $p_1$ then $p_2$ etc through to $t_2$, but I can make little sense of any of that until I can digest what this integrand looks like.

Answer (score 1):

the symbol $\mathcal P$ in your equation stands for a probability density function. In this case, the arguments are vectors. If you want, you can see it as a function that takes in three arguments ($\mathbf s$, $\mathbf p$, and $\mathbf t$) and spits out the density of that triple.

As for the shape of the joint density, it is probably not possible to write it (e.g., I'm missing some details about $\omega$). However, you can use the law of conditional probabilities to say that $\mathcal P(\mathbf s,\mathbf p ) = \mathcal P(\mathbf p|\mathbf s )\mathcal P (\mathbf s)$ (go on from there to complete the full joint distirbution).

As for the integral, that just means that the authors marginalize $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf t$ to find the density of $\mathbf s$ alone (you could in fact do as you wrote; i.e. integrate $s_1$, then $s_2$, and so on). In some way, you can interpret it as saying that you are looking for the distribution of the *skill* $\mathbf s$ of the players given the observed *ranking* $\mathbf r$ and *assignment* $A$ of players into teams. To find this density, you would need the *performance of the players* $\mathbf p$ and the *performance of the teams* $\mathbf t$; because these last two are not observed (they are [latent variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable_model)) you integrate them out to average their influence over all the possible values.

In general, in Bayesian modeling, models are constructed as [hierarchies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_hierarchical_modelingBayesian_hierarchical_modeling) of random variables that depend on other random variables until they define a big joint multivariate model; then the the model is conditioned on the observed variables and the latent variables are integrated out (marginalized, as in your example are $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf t$). In general, it is not possible to solve the integrals of the models and these are approximated. In the paper you pointed to, the authors use some variant of [expectation propagation](https://tminka.github.io/papers/ep/minka-ep-uai.pdf).

Comment: Yes $\mathcal P(\mathbf s,\mathbf p ) = \mathcal P(\mathbf s|\mathbf p )\mathcal P (\mathbf p)$  is the definition of a joint distribution. But alas therein lies my question. $\mathcal P (\mathbf p)$ is easy to understand for it is already defined above in the question. But what is $\mathcal P(\mathbf s|\mathbf p )$? Forgive me, I know it is $\mathcal P(\mathbf s)$ given $\mathbf p$ but as before the distribution of $\mathcal P(\mathbf s)$ is given above and it is completely independent of $\mathbf p$. To wit, how is $\mathcal P(\mathbf s|\mathbf p )$ different from $\mathcal P(\mathbf s)$?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I have corrected it. $\mathcal P(\mathbf s,\mathbf p) = \mathcal P(\mathbf p|\mathbf s)\mathcal P(\mathbf s)$. Where $\mathcal P (\mathbf s)$ is the first normal and $\mathcal P(\mathbf p|\mathbf s)$ is the second normal.

Comment: In other words, your second expression should be $P_i | S_i \sim \mathcal N(p_i|s_i, \beta^2)$; Hence, $\mathcal P(p_i|s_i) \propto \exp\{ - (s_i - p_i)^2 / (2\beta^2)\}$. From there, you can compute $\mathcal P(p_i)$ by integrating out $s_i$ from $\mathcal P(p_i) = \int \mathcal P(p_i,s_i) \mathrm{d} s_i$ and you get the second expression: $\mathcal P(p_i) = \mathcal N(p_i| \mu, \sigma^2 +\beta^2)$.

Comment: Does not $
\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}})
=
\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}},\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}})
=
\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}}|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}})
\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}})
=
\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{p}}|\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}})
\mathcal{P}(\boldsymbol{\mathrm{s}})$?

If so, are you choosing one of those simply for convenience (because P is a function of S)?

Comment: Yes indeed. Both forms are correct; however, as you pointed out, you do not have the marginal $\mathcal P(\mathbf p)$ so the first way is useless to us.

Comment: It's a standard Gaussian integral and it's solved by completing the square at the numerator until you have a Gaussian density (whose integral is known to be 1). See http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE598C/completingTheSquare.pdf for a reference on how to solve these integrals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77845/discussion-between-bernd-wechner-and-riccardo-sven-risuleo).